# Method level authorization using OAuth

Tags: mule, mule-component

I have a RAML file with two methods  POST and GET. Also I have two applications A and B. 
A should only be able to call POST and B should only be able to call GET.
I am using "OAuth 2.0 Access Token Enforcement Using External Provider policy." and oauthprovider module to generate oauth token for authentication.

```
<oauth2-provider:config name="OAuth_provider_module"
        accessTokenEndpointPath="oauth/token" providerName="CustomProvider"
        clientStore-ref="my-client-store" authorizationEndpointPath="oauth/authorize"
        listenerConfig-ref="https_listener_config" supportedGrantTypes="CLIENT_CREDENTIALS AUTHORIZATION_CODE"
        doc:name="OAuth provider module">
    </oauth2-provider:config>
```

Any advice as how can I achieve method level authorization using above policy or any other suggestions.